# expressjs // module.exports vs. http.createServer

Tags: node.js, express, server

Both :

```
app.listen( port, function () {
  .. doing stuff ..
});
module.exports = app;
```

and

```
http.createServer(app).listen(port)
```

Will do quite the same. What's the main difference ??

Comment: Good one thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `module.exports` here is just for testing or extending proposes, so you can require `app` in your test and work with it. In another hand, `app.listen` is much shorter and cleaner syntax.

Comment: So there is no fundamental difference you're saying ? I was originally asking cause using it with passenger, exports does not work, but createServer does

Comment: Do you mean "express", right? For a node, in case of `http` you just creating server manually, everything else remains the same so if it works with passenger use the way it works with a passenger.

Comment: Yep that does works the same; but as passenger is handling node differently and does a lot of things, i was concerned if changing this could lead to issues/downfalls; teying to understand better

Comment: @Ben, so your question should be "How to correctly integrate ExpressJS with Passenger?". And so you will have higher chance to get desired answer.

Comment: it could have, but I felt this way to ask more straightforward, as the concern was about this specific difference